# android studio Properties window does not shown correctly

Tags: android-studio, properties, components

I use Android Studio 2.3 32-bit version. In design mode, the properties window seems strange. This window includes only `ID`, `layout_width` and `layout_height`. Other property options couldn't show. Also, it does not allow to change anything.

So, it is not work properly and I don't know how to fix this. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: It is the parent layout, you need to add any widget to the parent layout. When you select the widget you will see other options like background,visibility etc.,

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no difference between them. Parent layout window and widget properties window is totally same.  When I select a widget ( button, textview etc.), nearly nothing is changed. Only the widget name which is the bottom of the properties window is changed.